# Having Issues With EV Code Signing

Tags: windows, windows-installer, digital-signature, code-signing-certificate

I have recently purchased EV Code signing certificate from DigiCert...

Now i am having issues to sign my installer executable files.

Currently (Till now) below is the process to make the installer:

**Step-1:**

My installer is configured in a way so, it will load all common files from it's child support directory.

like below files structure:

Setup.exe (it's only have application exe file and few other configuration file that changes time to time)

Support (Directory)

Support\DLL (Has DLL files that is required by my application)

Support\Others (Any Other files)

Support\ETC (Just for example purpose)

All those support files is resided on my server as they don't change frequently

so, i have created a wrapper installer.exe file and a script to handle the wrapper..

That wrapper installer.exe file also resides on my server

**Step-2:**

My script does below steps:

a) make the setup.exe with the updated application files.

b) upload setup.exe file to server

c) add (append) that setup.exe and all others required files at the end of wrapper installer.exe file

d) I Provide That wrapper installer.exe (single file) to my clients/users.

**Step-3:**

When that wrapper executes, it creates a temp folder in temp directory. extract all the files that is appended in itself. and run the setup.exe from that temp directory

I make this process, as i only have to change application file that is few kilobytes only (always below 1mb), but those support files are huge in size.

So, instead of having to upload all those files from my local computer each time.

i make this wrapper process to make update/upload process much faster.

**Now, The Problem:**

If i sign the wrapper.exe file and put it to server, but when my script append data to that file, it looses the certificate settings (it's no longer signed :( )

so, how can i overcome this situation..

**Update-1:**

As asked, below is the php code that used to append setup.exe file:

```
    //Appending Setup.exe file...
    $archive_File = 'files/' . $strFileID . '.exe';
    if (is_file($archive_File) == 1)
    {
        $strSize = filesize($archive_File);
        $strData = 'Setup.exe' . chr(0) . $strSize . chr(0) . file_get_contents($archive_File) ;
        file_put_contents($strArchiveFile, $strData, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
    else
    {
        exit ('following file does not exits: ' . $archive_File);
    }
```

best regards

Comment: You need to show some code of how you are appending and extracting these setup files by your wrapper.  You should point to a publicly accessible version of wrapper.exe.

Comment: signatures are embedded in the files themselves.  They don't just lose their signature unless there was some corruption or your script was appending unsigned versions of the files.

Comment: @selbie, sir, please check i have added sample/part of my codes.. best regards

Comment: Did you validate the hash of your originally signed setup.exe matches the hash of your extracted setup.exe file?  Go download [fciv](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533) if you don't have an md5 or sha hash tool to run from the command line.

Comment: @selbie, sir, i am not concerned about the setup.exe file, i am concerned about the wrapper (installer.exe) file.. because that is the file user will run..

Comment: Oh wait - are you appending to wrapper.exe *after* it's been code signed?  That's definitely guaranteed to lose your signature.

Comment: I thought originally you were code signing setup.exe, but then setup.exe was losing it's signature after it was extracted. Now that I've re-read your post, I think what you are saying is that you are trying to append on to an already code-signed wrapper.exe.  Which is it?

Comment: @selbie, yes you almost got it. I signed my wrapper (Insttaler.exe) then my script append data to wrapper and thus it looses the signed :(. i hope i am clear this time?

Comment: You can't do that.  See my answer.  Do the code-signing step after you append your files to wrapper.exe.

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify wrapper.exe after you've code signed it.  That's the whole point of code-signing - to validate that a virus or other tampering didn't occur on the signed executable.

I'm not sure why you are code signing wrapper.exe first, then appending the files to it afterwards.  You need to do the following steps:

1. Code sign setup.exe and all other binaries first except for wrapper.exe
2. Append setup.exe and all other files to wrapper.exe.
3. Then code-sign wrapper.exe after it's been fully built.

There are a lot of free tools that will generate a self-extracting archive that when run will prompt the user to run the setup.exe within it.  [7Zip will do this for free.](http://ntsblog.homedev.com.au/index.php/2015/05/14/self-extracting-archive-runs-setup-exe-7zip-sfx-switch/)

But it sounds like you need to build your wrapper.exe on demand right before it's downloaded. If that's the case, add the code signing script to your server code that builds the final wrapper.exe

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer sir, let me clear you a bit more. i know that's but problem is for example, now i do all those and my wrapper.exe size is 50MB+, and i upload it to my website/server. After few days i update my exe (man application file) and again i have to process all the files and upload wrapper exe that file size is 50MB+ while the application exe file is less than 1mb. Currently i just have to upload the setup.exe file and rest is done in my server.  i hope that is clear sir?

Comment: You need to consider other designs.  50MB doesn't sound like a whole lot to re-upload.  Are you on a dial-up modem?  :)  Standard practice would be to rebuild wrapper.exe with all the application files every time you update the main executable.  That's what a professional build environment would do.

Easier option, although non-standard,  is to have your php script code sign the binary as it gets generated.  Another alternative it that wrapper.exe doesn't contain any files, but instead it downloads the rest of the files, installs them, and runs setup from some well known URL embedded in it.

Comment: thanks a lot for being so helpful to me. yes sir, at your country 50MB upload may not be a issue, but here it is :(. 2nd i can't not sign on my server because 1st, it's a linux server, 2nd my Certificate is EV Code Signing That Use  A Token (USB drive) for signing.. i hope you knew that :).... best regards

Comment: I understand. But given the constraints you've outlined, there is no obvious solution. Consider the other option of having wrapper.exe be a downloader for the package.  If you could kindly upvote my answer, I'd appreciate it.  I'm exactly 1 upvote away from getting silver badge for these tags.  :)

Comment: of course i will up-vote, that's not a problem, i would do 2 or more up-vote if i could, by the way sir, i don't like web-based (where user need internet connection to download and install) installer :(. Ok it seems, i am out of solution then ;(.. np.. thanks again for your support

Comment: sir, can you please clear this confusion, say my application use few third party dll component and also execute (shell) third party executable (either command line mode or directly). so, do i need to also sign all those dll component and exe files or only my application exe is good enough?

Comment: Windows only warns users about running unsigned EXE programs that have the MOTW (Mark of the web) bit applied.  That is, any EXE that is downloaded through a browser or extracted through a ZIP file that was downloaded, are subjected to warning prompts and such.   So in your case, you should be OK with just signing your wrapper.exe.  But it's still a good idea to sign all the attached EXEs, DLL, and MSI files produced by your build environment.